# NavLink needs to be active on two routes React-Router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, nav

I have a few NavLinks like these:

```
<NavLink to="/dashboard" >
    <i className="icon icon-home-icon-01"></i>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/searchplatform" >
    <i className="icon icon-search-icon-01"></i>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/boxes" >
    <i className="icon icon-line-state-01""></i>
</NavLink>
```

I want the second Navlink to be active on two routes, `/searchplatform` and `/search/results`.

And, no I dont want to have two different `NavLinks` obviously!

Thanks indeed

Answer (score 5):

You should use `isActive` function prop on `NavLink`. This you can return `true` from this function for the routes you want.

Read more about `isActive` function prop [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func).

Comment: `isActive` does not seem to exist anymore (v6). I'm struggling to find a way to handle that behavior as well

Comment: @FlorianBoudot have you found any way to do this?

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil I'm sorry no. I must have changed the ux in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a ternary for the `to=<path>` inverting a matched location to a specific event page and the activeClassName for react router v5. This keeps the Navlink linkable and active for both `/event/<eventid>` and `/events`

```
<NavLink
    to={!location.pathname.includes('/event/') ? '/events' : '/event'}
    activeClassName='link__header--active'
    ...etc...
/>
```